# Double html tag in css Style Sheet

Tags: css

I am changing a wordpress stylesheet and found this

```
.banner ul ul
```

This is all part of .banner ul already, so i.e.

```
.banner ul {blabla}
  .banner ul ul {blabla}
   . banner ul ul ul {blabla}
```

I am wondering what this does, does this only target the second/third ul?

Comment: maybe not, it is probably style applied to a `ul` inside a `ul`

Comment: It's a `ul` inside another `ul`.

Comment: In a css selector a "space" represents a descendant selector. `.banner ul` will style all `ul` elements present inside `.banner` element. While styles defined with `.banner ul ul` will affect those `ul` only which appears inside another `ul` inside `.banner`.

Comment: It's for a `<ul>` inside another `<ul>` This is fairly common for dropdown menus and such, nothing special about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it wasn't a mistake (which doesn't seem to be), that represents css to be applied to an `ul` inside another `ul`, like so:

```
 <div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
        <li> 
            <ul> <----
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul> 
 </div>
```

Only what is inside that second `ul` will be affected by what's inside `.banner ul ul`

Answer (score 0):

The author of the stylesheet probably intends to provide a selector with greater specificity in order to override other existing styles which might affect a `<ul>` inside a `<ul>` (as others have mentioned).  It's very likely that your site may have inline `<style>` blocks or *other stylesheets* that also attempt to style the same element.  Though it may be identical to parent styles, by being more specific with the selector, this style will be more likely to be applied over conflicting styles.